# Android Image filter

Tags: android, android-image, android-framework

I am making app where in i want to add filters on images and save it on local as well as on server. Is there any Library to do filtering like Gray scale , Invert. I need help how to proceed with the app. If there is no library then suggest some mechanism to start with.

Comment: Try some of already available libraries: http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/download.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as reference http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/learning/tutorials/. He has many image filtering tutorials. But if you want something more like a package, try this one https://github.com/ragnraok/android-image-filter